# Nesting block tags doesnt work

Tags: templating, seo, blocks

I have pagination twig component that needs to inject seo links into  of page (rel canonical).

I tried to use `{% block %}` twig tag for this, but problem is that pagination component is already included in another `{% block %}` tag containing main content of page.

In short, im trying to do this:

layout.twig:

```
<html>
<head>
{% block seo %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
{% block main %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

page.twig:

```
{% extends 'layout.twig' %}

{% block main %}

some content..
{% include 'pagination.twig' %}

{% endblock %}
```

pagination.twig:

```
... pagination links

{% block seo %}
<link href="url" rel="canonical">
{% endblock %}
```

When im using this code, block seo is empty. 
Can this be achived some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it’s not possible for an included template to override the contents of a block in the parent template, or its layout.

You’d need to just override the `seo` block from `page.twig` do whatever you need to do from there instead.

```twig
{% extends 'layout.twig' %}

{% block main %}
  some content..
  {% include 'pagination.twig' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block seo %}
  <link href="url" rel="canonical">
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is then maybe option to set variable inside included file so that it is accessible inside parent file?

Comment: That's not possible due to the scopes of Twig. You'll need a plugin for it or change the structure